# Trying to identify a story about Sentient Trees

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy, teleportation, sentience

Trying to identify the title and author of a Science Fiction story about a human boy and girl who are on an alien world. Notable is the teleportation device that only allows non-living material or plant material sent to & from Earth, until the girl, with a telepathic sentient tree determine the problem and successfully shield themselves and make the transport. The aliens have a number of psionic/esp/mental talents and the overall theme of the book was the conflict between human culture, dependent on machines, and the alien culture which was interactive with Nature.

Comment: This sounds somewhat like one of the sequels to Ender's Game but I'm not really sure if it matches or not, it's been a long time since I read it...

Comment: The Ender's Game sequels have some sentient trees in them, but they aren't telepathic and they don't communicate at all. The other elements also don't match.

Comment: @Paul, *au contraire*.

Answer (score 4):

This does sound like Xenocide, by Orson Scott Card.

The girl is probably Jane, a <s>computer</s> sentient being come to life in the *philotic* (faster than light) connections between the ansibles.

She is able to transport inanimate objects, more or less by memorizing every detail of all the particles (using any computers across the galaxy in the network of ansibles for storage) and then simply "recreating" the object elsewhere.  However, she can't transport living things because there are too many details to recall—not enough storage space in binary memory for the amount of detail and complexity in living beings.

When she discovers the philotic connection with the Piggies' father trees, she is able to contact them and use their organic memory space for storage, thus allowing her orders of magnitude more detail and the ability to transfer living beings.

(Honestly, it doesn't sound so weird in the flow of the story.)

There are a lot of characters, so I'm not sure which boy you're referring to, but it's probably Milo.

Comment: Xenocide is actually the 3rd novel of the Ender Quartet series of novels. They are, respectively: "Ender's Game", "Speaker For The Dead", "Xenocide", and "Children Of The Mind". I actually very much enjoyed the Ender's Quartet, with SFTD & Xeno being the best two novels of the four IMHO. If you like Ender's, Game, I highly recommend the other 3 books, as well as the "Ender's Shadow" series.

Comment: This book doesn't take place on earth, the trees do not have "a number of [mental] abilities", and the first thing Jane transports is an entire spaceship full of people. The thing with Jane using the tree network is done because the ansible network Jane was living on was being shut down.

Comment: @Paul, look again; once the ansible network was shut down and Jane began using the tree network, she *then* realized she would have enough storage space to transport people.  I don't have the book handy but I'll find the exact passage later.

Comment: @Wildcard OK, I looked again. Jane transports a spaceship full of people in Xenocide, Chapter 17. The ansible network is shut down in Children of the Mind, Chapter 7, "killing" Jane. The solution to this problem comes in Chapter 9, when she is able to move her brain into the philotic web of the trees.

Comment: @Paul I stand corrected and humbly beg your pardon.